# Redirecting with slug in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In Razor Pages, how can I redirect to a URL that contains slugs?

For example, the code below takes me to the URL that contains rootValue:

```
return RedirectToPage("/EmailConfirmation", new {email = command.Email});
```

The output is like this:
https://localhost:5001/EmailConfirmation/example@gmail.com

But how can I use Razor Pages commands to go to the following URL that contains slugs?
https://localhost:5001/EmailConfirmation?email=example@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go to the following url:

```
https://localhost:5001/EmailConfirmation?email=example@gmail.com
```

You can try to use [PageModel.Redirect(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.redirect?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```
string queryString = "?email=" + command.Email;
return Redirect("/EmailConfirmation"+queryString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RedirecToAction`,

```
return RedirectToAction("EmailConfirmation", new { email = command.Email });
```

Given that you have an action named `EmailConfirmation` like,

```
public IActionResult EmailConfirmation([FromQuery] string email)
{  
   //your code
   return View();
}
```

Comment: question about razor pages, not mvc. In razor pages project u don't have RedirectToAction function, u also don't have controller with action EmailConfirmation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages